# mysql: storing math operation as a new database

Tags: php, mysql

I have table, from this table, I want to do some math operation (such as sum) then I want to save the result in a separate column from the table.

so this is my table

```
table: xxx

!  code   !   A  !   B  !   C  !
---------------------------------
!  0001   !   4  !   2  !      !
!  0002   !   2  !   1  !      !
!  0003   !   1  !   4  !      !
!  0004   !   3  !   5  !      !
```

then I use this code to call the query, and save the math operation.

```php
$mySql = "SELECT *  FROM xxx ORDER BY code ASC "; 
$myQry = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb)  or die ("Query salah : ".mysql_error());
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry))

$sum = $myData['A'] +  $myData['A']

$mySql  = "UPDATE xxx  SET C='$sum' WHERE code='$Kode'";
$myQry  = mysql_query($mySql, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal query".mysql_error());
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($myQry))
{
    $Kode = $myData['code'];
}
```

my problem is, it's not come up like what I want.
I want like this:

```
table: xxx

!  code   !   A  !   B  !    C  !
---------------------------------
!  0001   !   4  !   2  !    6  !
!  0002   !   2  !   1  !    3  !
!  0003   !   1  !   4  !    5  !
!  0004   !   3  !   5  !    8  !
```

but this is what I've got

```
table: xxx

!  code   !   A  !   B  !    C  !
---------------------------------
!  0001   !   4  !   2  !    6  !
!  0002   !   2  !   1  !    6  !
!  0003   !   1  !   4  !    6  !
!  0004   !   3  !   5  !    6  !
```

any help? I think, my code just take data from the first code, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues here and this task can be done much easier. However since this sounds like you are trying things and want to learn let's concentrate on you code.

The immediate problem is the structure of your code. You perform your math operation, however your structure does not store the result as you expect it to. You have to change the structure to something like that:

```
$selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM xxx ORDER BY code ASC"; 
$selectResult = mysql_query($selectQuery, $koneksidb) or die ("Query salah: ".mysql_error());
while ($myData = mysql_fetch_array($selectResult)) {
    $sum = $myData['A'] +  $myData['B'];
    $code = $myData['code'];
    $updateQuery = "UPDATE xxx SET C='$sum' WHERE code='$code'";
    mysql_query($updateQuery, $koneksidb) or die ("Gagal query: ".mysql_error());
}
```

Especially not the curly brackets used with the `while` command: `while (...) { ... }`.

A general warning: you are using the old, outdated and deprecated `mysql` extension here. You should take a look at the current alternatives `mysqli` or `PDO` and learn about the advantages of "prepared statements" and "parameter binding" for your code, so that you do not run into the typical issue of "sql injection vulnerability".

As mentioned in the beginning it certainly is possible to simplify this whole task by not performing the math computation in php, but directly in mysql. That way you would only need a single sql update statement which does all the job: `UPDATE xxx SET C=A+B;`. But as mentioned before your question looks like you are trying to work into this field, so it probably is a very good idea to first get your own code to work before moving on.

Comment: You are welcome! Keep up learning, good luck for future projects!

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're trying to do

```
UDPATE xxx SET C = A + B
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ***DO NOT USE*** the **deprecated** `mysql_*` API!

Second, you're grossly overcomplicating this. If all you want to do is add A + B and store the result in C *for each row*, you can do that in a single SQL query, as Tin Tran suggests.

The *complete* code would be

```
$query = "UPDATE xxx SET c = a + b";
mysql_query($query, $koneksidb) or die("Gagal query".mysql_error());
```

(These two lines would replace *all* of your code shown in the question.)

Although, as I said, you should immediately migrate to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.